# Install Ubuntu and erase Windows Vista for good

Tags: windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I remove Windows Vista from my notebook and only install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48838/can-i-remove-windows-vista-from-my-notebook-and-only-install-ubuntu)

I want install Ubuntu but I can't erase Windows Vista....
How to do it?
I have an Acer Aspice 4930.

/Gilbert

Answer (score 0):

erase,

that's simple...

Boot using live-CD and use entire disk( or use custom layout for advanced setup, with multiple partitions).

P.S. remember to format the partition containing Win Vista.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "can't erase Windows Vista". What did you try to achieve this?

The normal procedure would be:

1. Make a backup of your existing installation (just to be sure) and make sure the backup actually works
2. Restart your computer with the Ubuntu CD in the drive (or bootable USB stick inserted)
3. Your computer will now start from the CD or USB stick (if it doesn't, check the startup settings in the BIOS of your Acer Aspire, it might be set to boot from the harddisk directly)
4. Select 'Install Ubuntu'
5. Follow the steps and choose to use your entire harddisk for Ubuntu.

After the installation finishes, your computer should no longer have Windows Vista on it.