# which ubuntu instead of vista

Tags: dell, windows-vista

I have a Dell Studio 1735 laptop which came with Windows Vista Home premium 32bit.

I have been impressed today with a friends laptop running Ubuntu, am I able to run it on my laptop?

Do I need to delete Windows first?

Are there any key issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer disc also has a Live Environment. This allow you to try Ubuntu, without installing it. All you need to do is download the iso image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and follow the guide [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create a bootable USB stick, or [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) to burn to a DVD.

Then all you need to is select in 'Boot Device Selection' to boot from the DVD/USB stick, and it'll work. Yet another guide on selecting it to boot from is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)

There are some other helpful things here:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Reasons_for_Using_a_LiveCD_Session

The only things you need to be aware of is some hardware drivers, mainly for wifi or graphics. You can get some of these drivers, and proprietary audio/video codecs required to play media, by allowing 3rd Party Software to be installed, if you do try to install it.

Hope this helps, and enjoy Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

You can have Ubuntu alongside of your `Windows` . even you can install it on a USB Memory Disk or external storage devices . I offering you to use windows and `Ubuntu` at first if you're newbie . These topics are helpfull if you want to start :

> [Can I remove Windows Vista from my notebook and only install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48838/can-i-remove-windows-vista-from-my-notebook-and-only-install-ubuntu)
>
> [How to partition a disk for installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64671/how-to-partition-a-disk-for-installing-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: Good answer, just don't highlight things with code tags... or suggest edits with them ;-)

Comment: Errr... There is this: http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Apply cold water to burned area.