# can i install ubuntu on top of windows

Tags: system-installation, windows

I just got a computer with windows vista but I don't know the password nor do I even want windows on the computer. is there anyway to install ubuntu without knowing the password. I do have an installer disk for ubuntu 18.04.2. I don't mind erasing the hard drive. any ideas? I have tried just turning it on with the installer in the computer, and using 3rd party software.

Comment: When you install Ubuntu, you'll get the option of 'erase disk and install Ubuntu' (step 6 in my link) which doesn't require you to know any windows password (*if it's a bios/hdd password you may need it; but few use hdd passwords*).  I suggest you look at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Another duplicate: [Can I remove Windows Vista from my notebook and only install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48838/can-i-remove-windows-vista-from-my-notebook-and-only-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible but the computer HDD must have another disk partition. You've to format the partition and install ubuntu.

Comment: If he wants to overwrite his windows disk, he doesn't need another disk partition.